# java.lang.illegalstateexception: closed by using WSRequest : Play Java

Tags: java, rest, playframework, playframework-2.0, ws-client

I have created a `WSClient` according to the Play Documentation. And using that client object I use WSRequest to get my response. But all I'm getting is a `null` body and `0` as the server response code. And when I debug to where i request `get()` it says `java.lang.illegalstateexception: closed`.

Following is my code.

**WS Client**

```
 private WSClient wsClient() throws IOException {
   akka.stream.Materializer materializer = akka.stream.ActorMaterializer.create(akka.actor.ActorSystem.create());
    // Set up the client config (you can also use a parser here):
    scala.Option<String> noneString = scala.None$.empty();
    WSClientConfig wsClientConfig = new WSClientConfig(
            Duration.apply(120000, TimeUnit.SECONDS), // connectionTimeout
            Duration.apply(120000, TimeUnit.SECONDS), // idleTimeout
            Duration.apply(120000, TimeUnit.SECONDS), // requestTimeout
            true, // followRedirects
            true, // useProxyProperties
            noneString, // userAgent
            true, // compressionEnabled / enforced
            SSLConfigFactory.defaultConfig());

    AhcWSClientConfig clientConfig = AhcWSClientConfigFactory.forClientConfig(wsClientConfig);

    // Add underlying asynchttpclient options to WSClient
    AhcConfigBuilder builder = new AhcConfigBuilder(clientConfig);
    DefaultAsyncHttpClientConfig.Builder ahcBuilder = builder.configure();
    AsyncHttpClientConfig.AdditionalChannelInitializer logging = new AsyncHttpClientConfig.AdditionalChannelInitializer() {
        @Override
        public void initChannel(io.netty.channel.Channel channel) throws IOException {
            channel.pipeline().addFirst("log", new io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler("debug"));
        }
    };
    ahcBuilder.setHttpAdditionalChannelInitializer(logging);

    WSClient customWSClient = new play.libs.ws.ahc.AhcWSClient(ahcBuilder.build(), materializer);

    customWSClient.close();
    return customWSClient;
}
```

**Request Handler**

```
Future future = executorService.submit(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    WSRequest wsRequest = wsClient.url(url);

                    WSRequest complexRequest = wsRequest.setHeader(header.getKey(), header.getValue())
                            .setRequestTimeout(120000).setMethod(requestMethod);

                    CompletionStage<WSResponse> responsePromise = complexRequest.get();

                    CompletionStage<Result> promiseResult = responsePromise.thenApplyAsync(responseAfter -> {

                        int responseStatus = responseAfter.getStatus();
                        String body = responseAfter.getBody();
                        restResponse.setBody(body);
                        restResponse.setStatus(responseStatus);

                        return ok();
                    });

                }
            });
            future.get();

            executorService.shutdown();
```

I also use `ExecutorService` for asynchronous handling. 
I searched everywhere for this problem and I still haven't found any solution for it.

**Error in Debug**

[Debug Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lTFK.png)

**New Debug Error**

[Not Completed Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLGrG.png)

Comment: please add your error stacktrace and mention line number you got the error in actual.. @Akila

Comment: There is not error showing in the console. So i had to debug it. I updated my question with a screenshot of the debug

Comment: `customWSClient.close(); return customWSClient;` maybe that is the problem?

Comment: @Salem yep, that's the mistake.

Comment: @AkilaHettiarachchi "I also use ExecutorService for asynchronous handling" WSClient is already asynchronous (you get a CompletionStage)

Comment: @Salem Even without that It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the WSClient is being closed with `customWSClient.close()`. After this it is not possible to make requests.

Comment: I fixed it but now i am getting another error. It says scala.concurrent.java8.FuturesConvertersImpl$CF@7c2312fa[Not completed].

I have edited my question with the new debug.